# Overflow Error - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an Overflow error on the following line of code:

```
coukTotalBingBrandSessions = (convertStringToNumber(coukBingBrandSessions) + ((convertStringToNumber(coukBingBrandSessions) / (convertStringToNumber(coukBingBrandSessions) + convertStringToNumber(coukBingNonBrandSessions))) * convertStringToNumber(coukBingTNPSessions)))
```

I've done a bit of searching and most of the answers seem to relate to variable type. But I've checked through the variables and unless I'm totally blind (happy to admit) I can't see any inconsistencies that would interfere with the function.

convertStringToNumber is a function:

```
Function convertStringToNumber(convertNumber As String) As Long

If convertNumber > "" Then
convertStringToNumber = 0
Else: convertStringToNumber = CLng(convertNumber)
End If

End Function
```

And I have the following variables defined:

```
Dim coukBingBrandSessions As String
Dim coukBingNonBrandSessions As String
Dim coukBingTNPSessions As String
Dim coukGoogleBrandSessions As String
Dim coukGoogleNonBrandSessions As String
Dim coukGoogleTNPSessions As String
Dim coukPpcBrandSessions As String
Dim coukPpcNonBrandSessions As String
Dim coukBingBrandOrders As String
Dim coukBingNonBrandOrders As String
Dim coukBingTNPOrders As String
Dim coukGoogleBrandOrders As String
Dim coukGoogleNonBrandOrders As String
Dim coukGoogleTNPOrders As String
Dim coukPpcBrandOrders As String
Dim coukPpcNonBrandOrders As String
Dim coukOtherBrandSessions As String
Dim coukOtherNonBrandSessions As String
Dim coukOtherTNPSessions As String
Dim coukYahooBrandSessions As String
Dim coukYahooNonBrandSessions As String
Dim coukYahooTNPSessions As String
Dim coukOtherBrandOrders As String
Dim coukOtherNonBrandOrders As String
Dim coukOtherTNPOrders As String
Dim coukYahooBrandOrders As String
Dim coukYahooNonBrandOrders As String
Dim coukYahooTNPOrders As String

Dim coukSEOBrandSessions As Long
Dim coukSEONonBrandSessions As Long

Dim coukSEOBrandOrders As Long
Dim coukSEONonBrandOrders As Long

Dim coukTotalBingBrandSessions As Long
Dim coukTotalGoogleBrandSessions As Long
Dim coukTotalOtherBrandSessions As Long
Dim coukTotalYahooBrandSessions As Long

Dim coukTotalBingBrandOrders As Long
Dim coukTotalGoogleBrandOrders As Long
Dim coukTotalOtherBrandOrders As Long
Dim coukTotalYahooBrandOrders As Long

Dim coukTotalBingNonBrandSessions As Long
Dim coukTotalGoogleNonBrandSessions As Long
Dim coukTotalOtherNonBrandSessions As Long
Dim coukTotalYahooNonBrandSessions As Long

Dim coukTotalBingNonBrandOrders As Long
Dim coukTotalGoogleNonBrandOrders As Long
Dim coukTotalOtherNonBrandOrders As Long
Dim coukTotalYahooNonBrandOrders As Long
```

Cheers

Comment: Your 'if' statement is incorrect. Try if Len(convertNumber) > 0 and isNumber(convertNumber) then ... Also remove the ':' after your else statement.

Comment: What if you declared `coukTotalBingBrandSessions` as `Double`? (In addition to what @KrisB pointed out)

Comment: @BruceWayne it's defined As Long

Comment: @Kris B I tried your suggestion but it told me isNumber is not defined as a function and also it wouldn't let me remove the ":" it just keeps putting it back in so I changed the function to this:

Comment: Function convertStringToNumber(convertNumber As String) As Long

If convertNumber > "" Then
convertStringToNumber = CLng(convertNumber)
Else
'Do nothing
End If

End Function

Comment: it should be `IsNumeric` not `IsNumber`

Comment: And now getting the overflow error on a different line of code, it does that same thing just with different variables and has a longer character length:

Comment: Error on this line now: coukTotalYahooBrandOrders = (convertStringToNumber(coukYahooBrandOrders) + ((convertStringToNumber(coukYahooBrandOrders) / (convertStringToNumber(coukYahooBrandOrders) + convertStringToNumber(coukYahooNonBrandOrders))) * convertStringToNumber(coukYahooTNPOrders)))

Comment: Is it possible that you're dividing by 0?

Comment: Yes... that is possible...

Comment: Any suggestions on how to handle that? can I implement an IFERROR formula within VBA like I would to handle dividing by 0 on the worksheet?

Comment: For clarity, your function should be 'if (len(convertNum) > 0 and isNumeric(convertNum)) then convertStringToNumber = CLng(convertNum) else convertStringToNumber = 0 end if

Comment: Yeah, don't divide by 0, I don't know what else to say.... what do you want your function to do in the case of a divide by 0 operation? You could make a special divide function to handle it and say return 0 or something if you detect the denominator is 0.

Comment: If the result of the calculation (not the function) is an error, e.g. DIV/0 then I would like the variable coukTotalBingBrandSessions to equal 0. If I was just working with formulas in the worksheet I would wrap IFERROR around them and set the second parameter to 0. Unfortunately it is completely unavoidable that some of the variables equal 0 from time to time. The module pulls down daily data from an API in XML format and parses it, hence the need for the function because it parses it as strings. The data changes on a daily basis so sometimes zero's occur and I need to code to handle it.

Comment: If you have the possibility of dividing by zero, calculate the divisor *first*, then check to see if it's zero before performing the division.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the calculations in an

```
On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

And the code would run but I don't think it's the best way to deal with it, given it wasn't suggested.

@Comintern Doing some further work has revealed that I need to break the calculations down into their separate parts anyway so should then be able to easily implement your suggestion of checking the value of the divisor first.

I'll report back if I get stuck ;)

Cheers guys